# Filtering option in the sidebar

Tags: shiny

In the below sample code (ui.R) can we add filtering option in sidebar itself. For example, if you click Dashboard in the sidebar, the filtering option should be below that

[image]

Ui.R

```
library(shinydashboard)


ui = sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    menuItem("Widgets", icon = icon("th"), tabName = "widgets",
             badgeLabel = "new", badgeColor = "green")
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
            h2("Dashboard tab content")
    ),

    tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
            h2("Widgets tab content")
    )
  )
)

# Put them together into a dashboardPage
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Simple tabs"),
  sidebar,
  body
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many thing you can do.  See the two sample scripts below to get some ideas as to what is possible with filters in the Shiny world.

Filter with Combo Box:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

data(tips, package = "reshape2")
filter_vars <- c("sex", "smoker", "day", "time")

ui <- fluidPage(
  lapply(filter_vars, function(var) {
    selectInput(var, var, unique(tips[[var]]), multiple = TRUE)
  }),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_filter <- function(data, var) {
    if (length(input[[var]]) == 0) return(data)
    data %>% subset(data[[var]] %in% input[[var]])
  }  

  subsettedData <- reactive({
    tips %>% my_filter("sex") %>% my_filter("smoker") %>% 
      my_filter("day") %>% my_filter("time")
  })

  observeEvent(subsettedData(), {
    lapply(filter_vars, function(var) {
      selections <- unique(subsettedData()[[var]])
      if (length(input[[var]]) == 0)
        updateSelectInput(session, var, choices = selections)
    })
  })   

  output$table <- renderTable({ subsettedData() })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Filter as You Type:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

df <- mtcars

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Test"
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  box(title = "Test", width = 7, status = "warning", DT::dataTableOutput("df"))
)

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$df = DT::renderDataTable(df, rownames = FALSE,
                                  options = list(
                                    autoWidth = TRUE,
                                    columnDefs = list(list(width = '10px', targets = c(1,3)))))
}

# Shiny dashboard
shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the time. Actually I think u misunderstood my question. I was asking if we can out the filters in the sidebar (under Dashboard). Please refer my screen shot for reference:)